# Add metadata and coordinate system to tif file created with GDAL CreateCopy

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate

I want to convert ascii grid data files from Deutscher Wetterdienst to GeoTIFF using GDAL in Python, but I have problems adding the correct coordinate system (since DWD uses their own RADOLAN grid its a bit problematic).

I'm using CreateCopy() which as far as I have read is using the gdal_translate command.
In gdal_translate I would just add the correct values with appending `gdal_translate -a_srs="+proj=stere +lat_0=90.0 +lon_0=10.0 +lat_ts=60.0 +a=6370040 +b=6370040 +units=m"` but I can't find a way to do it in the Python API.

Is there a way to add these values while translating, or adding them after creating the file using the dataset return of .CreateCopy()?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.
I just found out that there is `gdal.Translate(dstName, src, options)` and `gdal.TranslateOptions(xxx)` it works fine with that